# mongodb set feature compatibility to 3.4 fail

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, mongodb-3.2

I want to enable the features of my Mongodb 3.4 after upgrading. I have sharded cluster enviroment And after I ran the commands:

```
use admin
db.adminCommand ({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4"})
```

In mongos instance I got the following output:

> {"ok": 1}

But when I try to check with it succeeded with command:

```
db.adminCommand ({getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1})
```

I get the following output:

> {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "no option found to get"}

And when I check in ops manager I see that the command did not work

Comment: And `db.serverStatus().version` command gives you `3.4.x` answer?

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran your command

```
 db.adminCommand ({getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1})
```

on a `mongos` instance. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/#view-featurecompatibilityversion) states in this case:

> The operation is undefined on the mongos instances. For a sharded cluster that has access control enabled, to run the command against a member of the shard replica set, you must connect to the member as a shard local user.

When you connect to a `mongod` instead, the command should work as expected.